# ASP.NET Core - Pesquisa em requisições GET

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Estou utilizando ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API e preciso realizar pesquisas por determinado tipo de campo, ou seja, no meu front eu posso escolher o campo que desejo fazer a pesquisa e o meu back-end precisa pegar esse valor.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<ResponseResult> GetAll()
{
    return _materialHandler.Handle(new GetAllMaterialCommand());
}
```

Nesse exemplo, tenho o método da minha controller, nele preciso receber parâmetros dinamicamente.
Exemplo: Preciso pesquisar o cliente pelo Nome e CPF ou somente pelo Nome.
Como faço para pegar nesse método os dados da pesquisa?

Comment: Não sei se entendi sua dúvida como sendo mais fácil do que ela realmente é, mas este link [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1) lhe ajuda? Se voce rolar um pouco, verá que ele ensina a fazer requisição GET, entre outras coisas.

Comment: Infelizmente não me ajuda. Gostaria de saber como recebo os parâmetros dinamicamente da pesquisa do front da minha aplicação.

Comment: Mostre o código, só com essas informações fica difícil entender o cenário. Mas pelo que eu pude compreender, você poderia utilizar ViewModels para refletir e fazer as validações e queries que deseja. Ou ainda uma estrutura mais complexa para implementar a rota de busca em suas Controllers... depedende muito do cenário e do que você realmente deseja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa criar uma controller referente ao seu objeto de dominío:

**ApiVersion = Versão da sua API**

**Route = Rota para acessar seu controller pela url**

**HttpGet = Você define que seu método será o verbo GET da requisição HTTP. O parâmetro que passo para o atributo ("buscarFotosMesCorrente/{codigo}") define qual a url que será utilizada para fazer a requisição. As chaves são utilizadas para enviar um parâmetro para o servidor, nesse caso estou enviando o código da instalação que é uma string (pois não estou definindo o tipo). Caso queira passar um parâmetro inteiro, pode passar da seguinte forma {identificador:int}. O nome do parâmetro no atributo HTTPGET deve ser o mesmo do parâmetro do método.**

```
using using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("processamento/[controller]")]
public class FotoController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("buscarFotosMesCorrente/{codigo}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BuscarFotosMesCorrente(string codigo)
    {
        var idEmpresa = base.IdEmpresa.Value;

        var item = await _service.BuscarFotosMesCorrente(idEmpresa, codigo);

        if (item == null)
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(item);
    }
}
```

No corpo do método você implementa a lógica que você deseja realizar na chamada desse método, como por exemplo buscar o objeto na base de dados (como você informou na sua pergunta).

Para chamar esse método ficaria da seguinte forma

```
http:localhost:5000/processamento/Foto/buscarFotoMesCorrente/AI1
```