# ASP.NET Core - Pesquisa por entidades filhas

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Estou precisando implementar uma API que recebe parâmetros para entidades filhas
Exemplo: api/Pedidos/5/Produtos ou api/Pedidos/5/Produtos/10.
Preciso pegar somente os produtos do pedido número 5 ou ainda, pegar somente o produto 10 do pedido 5.
Tenho essa API e necessito altera-la, para atender essa demanda.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseResult>> Get(Guid id)
{
   var response = await _userHandler.Handle(new GetOrdersCommand { Id = id });
   return response;
}
```

Gostaria de saber como posso implementar isso em minha API?
Em que controller ficaria a implementação se fosse para retornar somente o os produtos de um pedido?
Como será a configuração de rota dessa API

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @ReníciusPagotto, essa sua pergunta é a mesma dúvida da outra?
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/318682/asp-net-core-pesquisa-em-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-get

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891494/how-to-pass-receive-multiple-args-to-a-restful-web-api-get-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891494/how-to-pass-receive-multiple-args-to-a-restful-web-api-get-method)

Comment: @LeandroAngelo São perguntas com propósitos diferentes